# How to get Design > Name property of DGV column from Header Text property

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I am trying to go through un-checked items within a CheckedListBox1 and based on the values returned hide relevant columns within DataGridView1 but the issue is that the values displayed in CheckedListBox1 are the HeaderText property of DGV column and not the Name property which is required for hiding the column within DGV.

See below code:

```
For Each checked_item As Object In CheckedListBox1.Items
            If Not CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Contains(checked_item) Then
                DataGridView1.Columns("").Visible = False
            End If
        Next
```

Is there a way to retrieve "Name" property of DGV column when referencing the column's HeaderText property?

Comment: Please, remove `VBA` tag as it's not related to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the column name to hide the column. You need the column. The name is just a means to get the column. The issue is the way you're populating your `CheckedListBox`. Displaying the `HeaderText` makes perfect sense, because that's what the user actually sees. What you should be doing is putting the columns themselves into the `CheckedListBox` and just displaying the `HeaderText`. That way, the items are the columns, e.g.

```vb
Dim columns = DataGridView1.Columns.Cast(Of DataGridViewColumn)().ToArray()

With CheckedListBox1
    .DataSource = columns
    .DisplayMember = NameOf(DataGridViewColumn.HeaderText)
End With
```

The code you posted then becomes this:

```vb
For i = 0 To CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1
    Dim column = DirectCast(CheckedListBox1.Items(i), DataGridViewColumn)

    column.Visible = CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i)
Next
```

Note that you should generally set the `DataSource` last when binding but that doesn't seem to work with a `CheckedListBox`, which doesn't offically support data-binding. For that reason, the `DataSource` is set first.

EDIT:

I'm adding this after the comment was added to the question about the `ItemCheck` event and the checking of the items at startup. The key here is to not actually act on the event until the list has been initialised, i.e. all the items have been initially checked. One way to do that would be like so:

```vb
Private isLoaded As Boolean = False

Private Sub Form1_Load(...) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Bind the data and check the items in the CheckedListBox here.

    isLoaded = True
End Sub

Private Sub CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(...) CheckedListBox1.ItemCheck
    If isLoaded Then
        'Act here.
    End If
End Sub
```

The other way to is to prevent event being raised by not handling it while the initialisation is taking place. That can be done in a couple of ways but I'll leave that to you as an exercise if that's what you want to do.

As the `ItemCheck` event is raised before the state of an item changes, you will need to treat the current item differently to the other items. My loop above would become this:

```vb
For i = 0 To CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1
    Dim column = DirectCast(CheckedListBox1.Items(i), DataGridViewColumn)

    'For the item that is being checked/unchecked, use its new state.
    'For other items, use their current state.
    column.Visible = If(i = e.Index,
                        e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked,
                        CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i))
Next
```

That said, if all items are initially checked and all columns are initially visible, it's only the current item that you need to care about, so there's no need for a loop at all:

```vb
Dim column = DirectCast(CheckedListBox1.Items(e.Index), DataGridViewColumn)

column.Visible = (e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked)
```

Comment: Yes, I removed the comment thinking you may not seen it yet as I re-read the answer and tried it and it worked... too hot headed.... Just playing around with the code you provided as still having an issue where its not necessarily always when item is un-checked the column goes Visible = False, seems like when un-tick one, then another it messes up and then un-ticked = visible or ticked = not visible.

Comment: I have changed the binding code to what works correctly.

Comment: It is almost certainly the case that you're having issues because `ItemCheck` is raised BEFORE the state of the item changes. For that reason, you have to treat the item being checked or unchecked differently to the rest. That is beyond the scope of this question though, so you should try to use the information I provided about the event and post another question if you still need help.

Comment: Yes, thank you. As I prefer your solution the most in terms of binding the column to the CheckedListBox1 I will carry on with this and if unable to resolve will post another question where the objective will be something else. The issue in this question is resolved via your binding suggestion (I also did use the suggestion with isLoaded variable :) )

Comment: @Pawel, I decided that, given that I had already incorporated the `ItemCheck` event into my answer, how to use it properly was relevant. I have thus extended my solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
For Each checked_item As Object In CheckedListBox1.Items
        Dim oCol As DataGridViewColumn = DataGridView1.Columns _
            .Cast(Of DataGridViewColumn)() _
            .Where(Function(x) x.HeaderText = checked_item).SingleOrDefault()
        If oCol IsNot Nothing Then oCol.Visible = _
            Not CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Contains(checked_item)
Next
```

Note: `System.Linq` is required!

**[EDIT]**

> this code is executed in the .ItemCheck event. When the form starts up
> I loop through all available columns, populate CheckedBoxList1 and as
> default they are un-checked but I want them checked as I want the
> columns to be visible at start

If you would like to change the visibility of column of currently selected item in CheckListBox (in `ItemCheck` event), use this:

```
Dim oCol As DataGridViewColumn = DataGridView1.Columns _
    .Cast(Of DataGridViewColumn)() _
    .Where(Function(x) x.HeaderText = checked_item).SingleOrDefault()
If oCol IsNot Nothing Then oCol.Visible = _
    Not CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Contains(CheckedListBox1.SelectedItem)
```

Do you see the difference?

The main difference is: there's no `foreach` loop ;)

Comment: It works... but for some reason when I load up the form all columns but 1 are hidden, and they are visible when I un-check values within my CheckedListBox1. Just trying figure out LINQ to fix it, but you might be able to spot it faster...

Comment: To add, this code is executed in the .ItemCheck event. When the form starts up I loop through all available columns, populate CheckedBoxList1 and as default they are un-checked but I want them checked as I want the columns to be visible at start, so I loop through them all and check them, which may be related to this issue since the code you provided will execute on each column check when the form is loaded.

Comment: I understand that @jmcilhinney although I didn't think the ItemCheck was relevant until I tried the code provided by Maciej Los therefore I'm torn whether it should have been in the initial question from the start.

Comment: Makes sense, I will update the question accordingly... I do understand now I should of shown the whole process of populating the controls etc. which would of made this thread a lot easier to read for anyone else.

Comment: @MaciejLos thank you, I will keep your code as it will introduce me more to LINQ although for this issue I will go with the solution from jmcilhinney. Thanks!

Comment: My apologies. I mistakenly thought that some of the comments on this answer were actually on the question itself. I obviously didn't scroll up far enough. I will delete my comments here.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, your comments helped me to understand what Pawel was meant.